# Node v0.8.5 REPL: Cannot find module when requiring npm installed module

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node app with a `package.json` file declaring my dependencies.

I've run `npm install` to install those deps to a local `node_modules` folder, and when I run my app, everything works great.

The problem is when I try to spike out some new functionality by firing up the node REPL:

```
$ node           
> require('hubot');
Error: Cannot find module 'hubot'
```

In the REPL, it doesn't seem to know to look inside `node_modules`. Is this expected behavior, or is hubot weird?

Comment: are you running your REPL from the right directory? You need to run it from the root of your project (the parent folder of `node_modules`).

Comment: yep. same dir as package.json & node_modules.

Comment: @adamesque Did you ever figure out why this was happening? I'm seeing the same thing on Node 5 and I'm sure it's just some simple mistake I'm doing.

Comment: @Joe nope, I never did, and I don't use hubot anymore so this is no longer an issue for me. sorry!

Answer (score 6):

You can set the env variable `NODE_DEBUG` to see the paths that are tried by node:

```
export NODE_DEBUG=module
> require('toto')
Module._load REQUEST  toto parent: repl
looking for "toto" in ["/Users/laurent/repl/node_modules","/Users/laurent/node_modules","/Users/node_modules","/node_modules","/lusr/local/bin/node","/Users/laurent/.node_modules","/Users/laurent/.node_libraries","/usr/local/lib/node"]
```

Comment: The REPL only looked into globally installed node modules, not the ones installed only in the project folder. So this does not work.